# Stanford NLP returns : instead of NNP

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford NLP Parser (http://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/StanfordParser.html) to analyze sentences.

The problem is that there is an discrepancy betwwen the results from the library and the results from online demo page(http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp)

The problem is with the following sentence:

> the stage. Plus, he

When I run this online this is the output that I get:

> (ROOT   (NP (DT the) (NN stage) (. .)))
>
> (ROOT   (NP
>       (NP (NNP Plus))
>       (, ,)
>       (NP (PRP he))))

Please note that the `Plus` is identified as `NNP`

The problem is that the same sentence yields a slightly different output when processed by the lib:

> {(ROOT (FRAG (FRAG (NP (DT the) (NN stage)) (. .)) (: Plus) (FRAG (,
>   ,) (NP (PRP he)))))}

As you can see, the `Plus`is now identified as `:`

How do I force the lib to return NNP?

Here is the code:

```
      var sent = "the stage. Plus, he";
      var lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(modelsDirectory + @"\lexparser\englishPCFG.ser.gz");
      var f = PTBTokenizer.factory(new CoreLabelTokenFactory(), "");
      var s = new java.io.StringReader(sent);
      var w = f.getTokenizer(s).tokenize();
      s.close();
      var t = lp.apply(w);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you tokenizing on whitespace (the `tokenize.whitespace` property)? It seems like in your second example, the library is not splitting the passage into two sentences, which yields a different parse.

Also, more broadly, what are you trying to do here? These are sufficiently ungrammatical sentences that the parse is near meaningless (and the parser is near guaranteed to mess up), and the NNP tag on 'Plus' is also a mistake.

Comment: NNP tag on 'Plus' is a mistake?

Comment: Well, I'm unclear on what the semantics of the sentence actually is. But NNP is a proper noun, and Plus seems more like a connective (`CC`) than a proper noun.

Comment: I am just a developer, I don't know why they want this. My job is to make this consistent and right.

Comment: Not sure what tokenizer I use, added the code. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try the [simple API](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/simple.html)? Create a new `Document` with some text, call `.sentences()` on it, and then call `.parse()` on each sentence.